# iOS - Standard Icon Buttons - How to create an iCloud button

Tags: ios, button, uikit, navigationbar

Please have a look at the icons that apple describes at this page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/BarIcons.html

Have can I create a bar button with this iCloud upload icon?(Last row center in Apple's graphic)

[image]
 I can't find them anywhere documented.

Comment: hi Max, it looks like you accidentally posted this question twice. I've answered the other copy here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575459/ios-uibarbuttonitems-how-to-make-normal-uibuttons-with-the-standard-icons/23575542#23575542

Comment: Hey, This question is different. I'm asking specificially for that iCloud icon that I can not find in the list of possible UIBarButtonSystemIcons. (I edited the question)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the image to your `Images.cassets` folder into your project. After that you need to set the image for the button you want. Import the image as png preferable.

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"];
[yourButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```